# GridSearchCV for multi-label classification for each label separately

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am doing multi-label classification using scikit learn. I am using RandomForestClassifier as the base estimator. I want to optimize the parameters of it for each label using GridSearchCV. Currently I am doing it in the following way:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

parameters = {
  "estimator__n_estimators": [5, 50, 200],
  "estimator__max_depth" : [None, 10,20],
  "estimator__min_samples_split" : [2, 5, 10],
}
model_to_tune = OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0,class_weight='auto'))
model_tuned = GridSearchCV(model_to_tune, param_grid=params, scoring='f1',n_jobs=2)
print model_tuned.best_params_
{'estimator__min_samples_split': 10, 'estimator__max_depth': None, 'estimator__n_estimators': 200}
```

These are the parameters which gives the best f1 score considering all the labels. I want to find the parameters separately for each label. Is there any built in function which can do that?

Comment: Multi-label emphasizes on `mutually inclusive` so that an observation could be members of multiple classes at the same time. If you would like to train separate classifiers for each label, then for that particular classifier, each observation can only be a member of ONE class (one-vs-the-rest), which is `mutually exclusive`. Your desired approach seems to contradict with your actual multi-label observations, and  I don't think there is an implementation for this in scikit-learn.

Comment: @JianxunLi Hi, I am wondering if what ` OneVsRestClassifier` does is just binary relevance in multi-label literature. If so, not considering interaction between labels indeed is the major drawback of using binary relevance, so it should be the same when you train individual classifiers 'by hand' versus using `OneVsRestClassifier`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not hard to do that, though it is not built-in and I'm not sure I understand why you would want to.

Simply pre-process your data like so:

```
for a_class in list_of_unique_classes:
    y_this_class = (y_all_class==a_class)
    model_to_tune = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0,class_weight='auto')
    model_tuned = GridSearchCV(model_to_tune, param_grid=params, scoring='f1',n_jobs=2)
    model_tuned.fit( X, y_this_class )

    # Save the best parameters for this class
```

(Also, beware f1 score, it does not do a good job of describing performance of a classifier for skewed data sets. You want to use ROC curves and/or [informedness](http://www.flinders.edu.au/science_engineering/fms/School-CSEM/publications/tech_reps-research_artfcts/TRRA_2007.pdf)).

Comment: I tried using informedness for model selection. But when i applied the models on test data, for some classes, model predicted all the observations as 1, while actually the class has only around 5% of 1s. I did not face this while using f1 score. Why would this happen?